# How to see Windows's "default" colors in the properties window when using the designer?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, system-properties

It's a "quality of life" question, because there is no bug or anything, but it really annoys me.

You can see in Visual Studio, when you're editing your XAML properties, that for a given control, you can select "default" colors for **Background** and **Foreground** properties (for example), like **Chocolate**, **Salmon**, or plain **Red** or **Green** and so on.

The problem being that **you can not select them from a list**, you have to know them already, which is not really intuitive.

**Is there a way to show these "default" values for such properties in the Properties window of Visual Studio 2010?**

Comment: In code behind you can do System.Windows.Media.Brushes. to get a list and the just copy paste from there.

Comment: That's how I do it for now indeed D: